# ¿Cómo solucionar el error de anaconda con sublime text 3?

Tags: python, plugin, sublimetext3

[image: Error, me aparece al iniciar el sublime "plugin anaconda para python 3.6"]

¿Como solucionar este error?, me aparece al iniciar el sublime "plugin anaconda para python 3.6"

Comment: Podrías indicarnos qué versión de windows ténes? que versiónd e python tenés instalada? 2.7 como aparece en la imagen o 3.6 como decís o tenes las dos?

Comment: Tengo Windows 8.1 y  si tengo Python 3.6